# Shift cards over to next row when browser size is 915px width

Tags: html, css, svg

How do I shift the content over to the next row when browser width is 915px?

This is what I have now:

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="percent">
                    <svg>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="number">
                        <h2>90<span>%</span></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="text">Html</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="percent">
                    <svg>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="number">
                        <h2>85<span>%</span></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="text">CSS</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="percent">
                    <svg>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="number">
                        <h2>60<span>%</span></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="text">Javascript</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.container .card {
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  background: #222;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #1b1b1b, #222, #1b1b1b);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.container .card:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.percent {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #000;
  background: #222;
  z-index: 100;
}
.percent .number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.percent .number h2 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.card:hover .percent .number h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.percent .number h2 span {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #777;
}
.text {
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.card:hover .text {
  color: #fff;
}
svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #191919;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: translate(5px, 5px);
}
circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
}
.card:nth-child(1) svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * 90) / 100);
  stroke: #00ff43;
}
.card:nth-child(2) svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * 85) / 100);
  stroke: #00a1ff;
}
.card:nth-child(3) svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * 60) / 100);
  stroke: #c104ff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 915px) {
  /* your css of 1024 px screen size */
  .card {
    flex: 10% !important;
  }
}
```

How do I make the content shift downwards when on 915px browser width so it looks good on mobile. I've tried flex, change display, change width but nothing works. I don't know if it has to do with any of that but I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `grid` layout. First, set the container to `display: grid;`. After you can set how your grid will be with the `grid-template-columns: 1fr;` (1fr = one column, 1fr 1fr = 2 column, 1fr 2fr = 2 column, but the right one is bigger... etc). After that, you can add `gap: 1rem;` to have a gap between you column and row.

The [Grid Documentation on W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Here is a example:

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.container .card {
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  background: #222;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #1b1b1b, #222, #1b1b1b);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.container .card:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.percent {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #000;
  background: #222;
  z-index: 100;
}
.percent .number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.percent .number h2 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.card:hover .percent .number h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.percent .number h2 span {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #777;
}
.text {
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.card:hover .text {
  color: #fff;
}
svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #191919;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: translate(5px, 5px);
}
circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
}
.card:nth-child(1) svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * 90) / 100);
  stroke: #00ff43;
}
.card:nth-child(2) svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * 85) / 100);
  stroke: #00a1ff;
}
.card:nth-child(3) svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * 60) / 100);
  stroke: #c104ff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 915px) {
  /* your css of 1024 px screen size */
  .card {
    flex: 10% !important;
  }
  .grid-class{
      display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="container grid-class">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="percent">
                    <svg>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="number">
                        <h2>90<span>%</span></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="text">Html</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="percent">
                    <svg>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="number">
                        <h2>85<span>%</span></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="text">CSS</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="percent">
                    <svg>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="number">
                        <h2>60<span>%</span></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="text">Javascript</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```